# ios app crash say NSNull rangeOfCharacterFromSet

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull
>   rangeOfCharacterFromSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x30e483d0'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x22ebcf87 0x304dfc77 0x22ec237d 0x22ec0259 0x22ec1548 0x26665113 0x267b8e03 0x267b8ed7 0x25d5ebd1
>   0x25d5ea59 0x25d5e447 0x25d5e251 0x25d5815d 0x22e83845 0x22e80f29
>   0x22e8132b 0x22dcedb1 0x22dcebc3 0x2a133051 0x2639aa31 0x327d63
>   0x30a7baaf) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of
>   type NSException

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: You are assuming something that is an `NSNull` is an `NSString`. Check the variable to see if it is an `NSNull` before doing whatever you are doing to it, and don't do it if it is. For more specific advice, please post the code that is going wrong.